# Equivalent XAML line to this C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In a WPF app, what XAML code do I need to do the same job as this line of c#:

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you could do:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}}"
```

I've just tried it, and it seems to work...

EDIT: As noted in comments, apparently you can also use:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

... but I haven't tried that.

Comment: I would write that as `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}`, a bit shorter and such.

Answer (score 2):

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <Binding  Path="ViewModel"></Binding>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

ViewModel is a public property in your code behind.